# Calculated Member value incorrectly

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I have the following table:

```
NoPax   QExch   Base Cost   Sale Price
2   1   1826.1  2377.06
2   1   1858.62 3753.74
2   1   2011.51 3178.34
2   1   2048.2  4017.2
2   1   2182.15 4243.2
1   1   2371.44 3705.5
2   1   2504.81 4198.7
2   1   2612.48 4482.02
2   1   2862.87 5017.08
3   1   3013.52 5215.17
2   1   3105.5  4926
3   1   3187.06 4698.05
2   1   3844.22 5780
2   1   4034.41 7182.75
2   1   4308    5498.1
2   1   4641.6  6045.35
3   1   4862.16 7750.51
2   1   4952.55 7612
5   1   5019.35 8916.57
2   1   5028.46 5744
```

The calculation I do is for profit ((Sale Price / QExch) - Base Cost) / NoPax

So I created a calculated field for the profit. However, I get a lot of negative results because for sum reason it sums the QExch for each row. Meaning in this example: QExch = 20 so for each row it does ((Sale Price / 20) - Base Cost) / NoPax which results with negative numbers.

My Query:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY {([Fact Lead Pax Report].[Brand ID].[Brand ID],[Measures].[No Pax]),([Fact Lead Pax Report].[Brand ID].[Brand ID], [Measures].[Est Profit] )}
ON 0,  
NON EMPTY [Fact Lead Pax Report].[Channel].[Channel]
ON 1
FROM [Lead Pax Report]
```

This is my calculated field:

```
(((([Measures].[T Tl Quote Price]/[Measures].[Q Exch])-
[Measures].[T Tl Base Cost])) / [Measures].[No Pax])
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like QExch isn't being split by your dimension. Have you set up all your dimension relationships?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you mean by "set up all your dimension relationships?" (I'm new to SSAS and MDX)

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I've only dabbled in SSAS myself. Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175669(v=sql.90).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365387(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Are you using Tabular or Multidimensional?  If Multidimensional, do you have everything set properly in your dimension usage tab?  If Tabular, are all of your relationships defined properly in the diagram view?

Comment: Looking at your problem, I can't help wondering whether in the example given (QExch = 20 so for each row it does ((Sale Price / 20) - Base Cost) / NoPax which results with negative numbers.), SalePrice is the total price as opposed to the unit price, in which case either the data in Sale Price is wrong, or the equation is incorrect.